# How to change tab indicator color in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, indicator

I want to change tab indicator color in android. Default color for tab host in android app is blue. I want to change to some other color. Please help me.

My code is as follows:

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/btn_color"
        android:layout_height="5dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBookConfirm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_text"
        android:background="@color/btn_color"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

My java code is as follows:
`
public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(TabHostActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.plays))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs

    intent = new Intent().setClass(TabHostActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.movies))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(TabHostActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("contact")
            .setIndicator("",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.events))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}`
```

I have attach image for the same. I just want to change blue color line present below selected tab.

---

[image]

Comment: Check this link - http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:setLeftStripDrawable="@color/your_custom_color
```

create a custom color resources in res->values folder and refernce this to there

Answer (score 1):

You should look a at the [docs for TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#attr_android:tabStripLeft). You have to use the `android:tabStripLeft` and `android:tabStripRight` XML properties to change the background color.

Easiest way would probably be to crate an 1px x 1px png with the color you want and place it in your `drawable` assets directory in your project, and use that.

Comment: Can you elaborate it with example or give me some additional code snippet so that I will get clear idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your color"`

Comment: is it with design library or related to appcompat fragments?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programatically using:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TAB_LAYOUT);

tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(YOUR_COLOR));
```